# How do i make random chat spawns using discord.js using node,

Tags: discord, discord.js

So basically im making an economy based discord bot and i want to make something like a `wallet drop`
and i want to make it so that it sends in any channel at a randomized time, i myself dont know where to start because i have the idea just no idea on how to do such a thing. i want it to be like the example below.

**A wallet has been droped, use /grab to pick up the wallet and take the cash**

and from there when the user uses the command they will get a randomized amount of money

```
let hrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
message.channel.send(`You have picked up the wallet and have gotten ${hrandom} from it!`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`client.setInterval`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval) to repeatedly execute code. Using `client.setInterval` instead of `setInterval` means that the interval is automatically removed when the client is destroyed.

For the `/grab` part, use a [message collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) to wait for a user to respond.

```js
setInterval(async () => {
  // In this example, is a 10% chance that a wallet will be dropped every 5 minutes
  if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('the guild ID that you want to drop the wallet in')
    // Alternatively, to choose a random guild use
    // const guild = client.guilds.cache.random()
    // Choose a random text channel
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'text').random()

   
    // Wait until someone responds with /grab or a minute
    const {author} = (await channel.awaitMessages(
      // Discord.js v12:
      /* msg => msg.content.trim() === '/grab',
      {max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']} */
      // Discord.js v13:
      {
        filter: msg => msg.content.trim() === '/grab',
        // If you don’t want it to time out, remove the time property
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ['time']
      }
    ).catch(() => {
      // Because time is specified as an error, the promise will reject when nobody responds
      // after a minute.
      // Do whatever you want here.
    })).first()
    // author is the user who grabbed the wallet
    let hrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000)
    await channel.send(`You have picked up the wallet and have gotten ${hrandom} from it!`)
  }
}, 300000)
```